# init object inline and pass as parameter - java

Tags: java, java-8

Why is orElse executed everytime even though it shouldn't?
What am I doing wrong here? I am still learning java :)

```
 Optional.ofNullable(myVar)
          .orElse(Optional.ofNullable(myVar = ...)))
                .orElseThrow(MyException::new))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `orElseGet()`. It accepts a `Supplier` and it will be invoked only when needed. E.g.

```
Optional.ofNullable(myVar)
      .orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(myVar = ...)))
            .orElseThrow(MyException::new))
```

To clarify: the argument you provide to `orElse()` is evaluated, but `orElse()` itself is not called. It's a side effect in your case, and you should use `orElseGet()` if you want to delay it's execution to when it is needed.

Comment: Why is it side effect? a bug in compiler or what? explain me pls I want to know why to be able to avoid those side effects in futher programming

Comment: Java evaluates method arguments before invoking said methods. In your case you provide an argument to `orElse()` and java happily evaluates that to prepare for method invokation. So even though `orElse()` is not called, your argument that you pass to `orElse()` will be evaluated.

Comment: …and that’s so much better than `if(myVar==null) { myVar=…; if(myVar==null) throw new MyException(); }` or, for those liking the inline style, `if(myVar==null && (myVar=…)==null) throw new MyException();`…

Answer (score 1):

> xplain me pls first whyyy???  – Ckkn

The method `orElse()` expects an object which must be created before the call of the method is executed. This (already existing) object is returned if the `Nullable`s content is actually `null`.

The method `orElseGet()` also expects an existing object, but this object is not returned itself. The expected object is of type `Supplier` which has a single method to be invoked when the `Nullable`s content is actually `null`.
This way you can avoid creating your value object every time the `orElseGet()` is invoked. But you "buy" this by creating a `Supplier` object instead. On the other hand the `Supplier` object could easily be an instance member or a constant...